# Is passing pointer by value or by reference the same

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

What is the difference between passing a pointer by reference and passing a pointer by value in C?

My understanding is when you pass arguments to methods a new stack frame is created and those values are copied to different memory addresses unless passed by reference. If passed by reference the memory addresses are passed.

When working with pointers I noticed that if I pass a char* by value and modify it in a different stack frame when I return back to the main stack frame the value of the ptr has been modified.

I wrote short code to show what I am talking about.

```c
//test pointer ref
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void passbyval(char const *lit,char* str){
    printf("---passbyval---\n");
    printf("%s\t%p\n",lit,&lit);
    //modify string
    strncat(&str[2],"/",1);
    printf("%s\t%p\n",str, &str);
}
void passbyref(char const **lit, char** str){
    printf("---passbyref---\n");
    printf("%s\t%p\n",*lit,&*lit);
    //modify string 
    strncat(&(*str)[1],"/",1);
    printf("%s\t%p\n",*str,&*str);
}
int main(){

    char const *litstr = "hello this is a test";
    char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);
    printf("---main---\n");
    //print original value and address
    printf("%s\t%p\n",litstr,&litstr);
    printf("%s\t%p\n",str,&str);
    passbyval(litstr,str);
    //modified value and address from pass by value 
    printf("\nretfromval:%s\t%p\n",str,&str);
    passbyref(&litstr,&str);
    //modified value and address from pass by ref
    printf("\nretfromref:%s\t%p\n",str,&str);
    free(str);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output
[image]

Is it good practice to not pass by reference `char*` you want to modify in void methods?

Scratching my head on why I would ever use pass by reference for pointers if the value they are referencing are implicitly passed by reference.

Maybe I'm missing something can some explain this a little better?

Comment: Suppose you have a function that takes in a pointer and may modify that pointer. Wouldn't it be perfectly reasonable to pass the pointer to the function by reference?

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" in C, there is only pass by value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Before C++ adopted the term “reference” for a built-in feature of the language, it was used in the context of C to mean manually passing a pointer. In fact, it still is used that way, and the C standard says that a pointer provides a reference to an object. When somebody says, in the context of C, that something is passed by reference, they mean the source code passes the address of that thing. This past and present use of the English language in the context of C **did not change when C++ development adopted the term for its own use for a different purpose**.

Comment: @Eric: everything you say is true, but the OP does seem to be mixing terminology from C and C++. I think the answer to his intended question is that, passing a pointer by address/reference is only necessary if the pointer itself is to be modified. If one only wishes to modify the target of the pointer, passing the pointer by value is fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you give a scenario where you would want to modify just the ptr and not the contents it points at? Thanks!

Comment: @mzimmers exactly, if you intend to change the contents of the pointer its good practice to pass char* by value? Seems dirty to me, just wanted to know if it could lead to problems down the road in memory. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle - there is absolutely nothing wrong with passing a pointer by value -- it's a bread-and-butter feature of C.

Comment: Kyle C, C spec uses _referenced type_ as grouping of object pointers and function pointers.  So in C, "by reference" implies via a pointer.  Other languages define "by reference" differently. So the question "passing pointer by value or by reference" needs specificity on the word "reference".  Are your asking a C question using C's usage of reference?  If not, you need to define "by reference".

Comment: @KyleC Re: "can you give a scenario where you would want to modify just the ptr and not the contents it points at?" --> `char *end = 0; strtod(nptr, &end);` may fit the bill. Function changes `end`, but not  `end[]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Im going to have to refer to Eric's original comment above. I am trying to manually pass a pointer, not a copy of a pointer, to the 'sub routine' stack frame. Essentially I am passing a pointer to a pointer, when I say pass by reference in the context of c.

Comment: @KyleC The most common one is where the caller may or may not have a buffer. You can pass a pointer to the buffer by reference. If there's no buffer, you pass a reference to a NULL pointer, allowing the function to set the caller's variable to the new buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What is the difference between passing a pointer by reference and passing a pointer by value in C?*

There is no such thing as *passing a pointer by reference* in C, all variables are passed by value, even pointers.

> *My understanding is when you pass arguments to methods a new stack frame is created and those values are copied to different memory addresses unless passed by reference. If passed by reference the memory addresses are passed.*

Again, the pointers are not passed by reference, a copy of the value stored in the pointer is passed, *i.e.* the address where it points to, you can test this by changing the value of the pointer inside the function, and check how that reflects on the original pointer, spoiler, it doesn't.

> *When working with pointers I noticed that if I pass a char* by value and modify it in a different stack frame when I return back to the main stack frame the value of the ptr has been modified.*

What you are passing is an address, a memory location where some data is stored, when you change the data stored in that memory address it will be permanent, no matter where you do it, in fact that is one of the advantages  of using pointers, for you to change the contents of some variable outside the scope where it's declared.

Comment: For sure I agree with everything you are saying. When I say by reference I think you know what I mean but for clarity I'm referring to the memory address of that pointer being copied in the sub routine stack frame.  Thanks!

Comment: @KyleC I understand, I just wanted to stress that in C everything is passed by value, I see you already have some good knowledge about these matters, don't take my answer as criticism, in most cases terminology is important.

Comment: No worries, I take any helpful advise/criticism, so thank you for your input. Just to conclude its standard/good practice in c programming to modify strings in methods without passing the original address? Thanks!

Comment: @KyleC if you pass a modifiable string, *i.e.* a modifiable null terminated array of characters, you will be passing the original string, a pointer to it, so if you modify it, it will modify the original, you can make a copy of it though, inside the function it you intend to modify it without modifying the original. if you pass a pointer to a string literal, on the other hand, that is not safe to modify and you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

> When working with pointers I noticed that if I pass a char* by value and modify it in a different stack frame when I return back to the main stack frame the value of the ptr has been modified.

None of your examples do this. Also, none of your code prints the value of `litstr` or `str`. To print the values of the pointers, remove the `&` in all of your `printf` calls. Then you will see the values of the pointers are the same in the calling routine and the called routine.

In `main`, `printf("%s\t%p\n",litstr,&litstr);` prints:

- the string that starts in memory at the address that is the value of `litstr` (because of `%s` and `litstr`) and
- the address (not the value) of `litstr` (because of `%p` and `&litstr`).

Similarly, `printf("%s\t%p\n",str,&str);` prints the string at `str` and the address of `str`.

In `passbyval`, `printf("%s\t%p\n",lit,&lit);` prints the string at `lit` and the address of `lit`. Since `lit` is a parameter to `passbyval`, it has its own address, which is different from the address of `litstr`. If you had printed the values of `litstr` and `lit`, instead of their addresses, you would see they are the same.

Similarly, `printf("%s\t%p\n",str, &str);` prints the string at `str` and the address of `str`. The address of the parameter `str` in `passbyval` is different from the address of the local object `str` in `main`, but their values are the same.

In `passbyref`, `printf("%s\t%p\n",*lit,&*lit);` prints the string at `lit` and the address of `*lit`. Since `lit` is the address of the `litstr` in `main`, `*lit` is that `litstr`, so `&*lit` is the address of `litstr`. The value of `litstr` would be `*lit`.

Similarly, `printf("%s\t%p\n",*str,&*str);` prints the string at `*str` and the address of `*str`, which is the address of `str` in `main`.

Comment: Im not sure if im understanding correctly but I intentionally printed out the value and the address of the string... Correct me if I am wrong but the & specifies the offset address of the char(BYTE) I am pointing to in string and when you print %s that prints every BYTE of string buffer until "\0" is encountered. So I intentionally added them. If you look at the output you will see the pointer address remain the same when you pass by ref and change when you pass by value. This was my intent to show the pointers address change but the value returned to main stack remains same.

Comment: By remain the same I mean the value that is manipulated in the method is returned to the main stack frame

Comment: @KyleC: After `char const *litstr = "hello this is a test";`, `litstr` is not a string. It is a `char *`, which is a pointer to a `char`. So `litstr` is a pointer. It points to the first character of a string. `&litstr` is the address of the pointer. It is not the address of the string.

Comment: when you pass a char const (**ptr) its still a char const *ptr, it does not decay to a char* ptr, if you attempt to modify this string you will get a bus error. 

Right the demonstration of this is to show when you pass a "pointers address by value" (what I called reference but C only has pass by value) the POINTERS address is changed, not the VALUE of the ptr it points too. 

I clearly demonstrated this with my output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the pointers and arrays work.

`pointer` is a separate object having its own reference, holding the reference of the underlying object.

```
char *p = "aaa";

print("%p\n", (void *)p); //prints the reference of the string literal "aaa"
print("%p\n", (void *)&p); //prints the reference of the pointer `p`
```

Arrays are contignous chunks of memory. Arrays *decay* to pointers. Those pointers do not have physical representation in the memory and only are references to the first element of the array.

```
char p[] = "aaa";

print("%p\n", (void *)p);  //reference of the first element 
                           //of the array p the type is `char *` 
                           //(pointer to char)
print("%p\n", (void *)&p); //reference of the first element of the 
                           //array p the type is `char (*)[4]` 
                           //(pointer to an array of 4 char elements)
```

Comment: Uhhh what... I think I understand the difference between heap and stack memory. Thanks!

Comment: I did not write anything about heap and stack

Comment: I also did not write anything about the difference between arrays and pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between passing a pointer by reference and passing a pointer by value in C.

In C, there are various ways arguments are pre-processed before being passed to a function.

- **No processing**
  A copy of the argument is given to the function. `char *s = ...; puts(s);`. `puts()` is given a copy of `s`.
- **Usual argument promotion**
  The argument is promoted to `int, unsigned, double, ...` before a copy is given to the function.  `float fl = 12.5f; printf("%g", fl);`  `printf()` is given a copy of `double 12.5`.
- **Function converted to an address**
  With `tss_create(tss_t *key, tss_dtor_t dtor);`,  `tss_dtor_t` is a function pointer type `void (*)(void*)`.  `tss_create(... , foo)` does not take a function `foo()` and pass that.  Instead a copy of the address of the function is passed.
- **Array converted to address of its first element**
  With `char s[] = "Hello; puts(s);`, A copy of `&s[0]` is passed to `puts()`.

Now, are any of these like OP's [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626030/is-passing-pointer-by-value-or-by-reference-the-same-in-c?noredirect=1#comment124851714_70626030)?

Yes.

> With `char *end[1]; strtod("123.4", end);`, *from the caller's point of view*, `end` is adjusted in it *entirety* by `strtod()` and so acts and smells like "pass by reference" from the caller's POV.  This is technically still "pass a copy", but the copy is the address of the argument's 1st element.

Other than that, I see no comparable "passing a pointer by reference and passing a pointer by value in C" in which to find a difference.